# JPA @Index annotation doesn't work

Tags: jpa, spring-data

I want to add index to one of the columns in my table, but it always complained that column is not found, I checked the table, the column exists!

If I removed that index annotation from the entity object, it works fine.

If I change columnList to the field name, eg, columnList="reportOwnerId", it fails with same message: 'database column not found'

how can i make it work? thanks

here is my entity class:

```
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Index;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "schedules",
        indexes = { @Index(name = "SCHEDULE_OWNER_GUID_INDEX", columnList = "report_owner_guid")}
        )
public class ReportSchedule extends AbstractTimestampEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Setter
    @Column(name = "report_owner_guid", nullable = false, unique = false)
    private String reportOwnerId;
...
```

and here is the error message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unable to create unique key constraint (report_owner_guid) on table schedules: database column 'report_owner_guid' not found. Make sure that you use the correct column name which depends on the naming strategy in use (it may not be the same as the property name in the entity, especially for relational types)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildUniqueKeyFromColumnNames(Configuration.java:1682)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1457)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
```

Later I figured out it might caused by the fact that column is not unique, and I updated the index to :

```
@Table(name = "schedules",
            indexes = { @Index(name = "SCHEDULE_OWNER_GUID_INDEX", columnList = "report_owner_guid", unique = false)}
            )
```

it still failed with the same error.

Comment: What if you change it to `columnList = "reportOwnerGuid"`?

Comment: @Cepr0: i get the same error if i change it to 'reortOwnerGuid'

Comment: Are you allowing your JPA provider to generate the database? If so what mode are you using? create, create-drop, validate, update? Have you checked if the column actually exists?

Comment: @greyfox: yes i allow JPA provider to generate the database, "setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create")", I did drop/re-create the database before I run the code

Comment: did you check the database columnname ? 

I wanted to comment as I arrived here, if you have multiple columns there is a space required after the commas, otherwise you get this error.